# writing an array to a cell in an Excel file

Tags: python, arrays, excel, openpyxl

I have an array and intend to write it to a cell in Excel file. This is what I have written:

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active
ws.cell(row =1, column=2,value = array)
```

However, this is what appears:

```
raise ValueError("Cannot convert {0!r} to Excel".format(value))
ValueError: Cannot convert array([ 0.05636739, -1.0995235 ,  1.5621883 ,  0.23029989, -1.0048712 ,
        0.2968822 , -0.70565003,  0.980125  , -0.8437103 ,  0.61934054,
        2.0164294 ,  1.1749456 , -0.5825496 ,  0.0223734 , -0.3009992 ,
       -1.4909168 , -0.31345168, -0.2767412 , -0.8971678 , -1.1039274 ,
       -0.85181683, -0.16889095, -3.1210947 ,  0.02482696,  0.12225098,
       -0.6535463 , -0.44520944,  1.1683434 ,  0.45652604,  1.036608  ,
        0.10676127,  0.14357172, -1.1680435 ,  0.9394648 ,  0.86175704,
       -0.9481152 , -0.61173934,  0.06488147,  0.97073036,  0.24283405,
       -2.0439208 , -1.698466  ,  2.4012387 ,  0.45818126, -0.43852893,
       -0.9148734 ,  0.72079426,  0.7851535 , -0.7290141 ,  0.6462927 ,
       -0.02162193, -0.13589399,  1.159382  ,  0.6197715 ,  0.6868322 ,
       -0.26407108,  0.5959033 ,  0.6035499 , -0.36849284,  1.1357089 ,
        0.58538085, -0.88665897,  1.1236175 , -0.4649693 , -0.37097642,
        0.49457297,  0.8635137 , -0.50415665,  0.7048566 ,  0.95307064,
        0.92260027, -0.94126046,  0.664093  ,  0.73268044,  1.5148633 ,
       -0.35993278,  1.6198764 ,  0.7880315 ,  0.32650006,  1.1038091 ,
       -0.9126403 , -1.6570944 , -1.3555399 , -1.9593365 , -1.1097077 ,
       -0.41850403, -0.1392701 ,  1.5849863 , -0.19829401,  0.22036958,
       -0.12666762, -0.61043185,  0.05952802,  2.5408616 ,  1.5259178 ,
       -0.3422841 , -0.40555838, -0.6363599 , -0.8635243 , -0.00665558,
        0.15131243,  0.18074986, -0.51952434,  1.1674523 ,  0.2348943 ,
       -0.16456501,  0.12222623, -0.8483792 ,  0.63505876,  0.59282553,
       -1.0182037 , -0.98936766,  2.5243523 ,  1.27921   ,  1.1834651 ,
        0.35722128,  0.67636305,  0.08398098, -0.09863412, -1.8910272 ,
        0.6978843 ,  0.75396585,  0.12672533, -0.35542056, -1.0139618 ,
       -2.023965  ,  0.8246543 , -0.33283824, -0.99150425,  0.8465382 ,
       -1.3770554 ,  1.0512654 ,  0.3017207 , -0.01521344,  0.2868532 ,
        0.5822116 ,  0.8829187 ,  0.62899995, -2.2099032 ,  0.9080436 ,
        0.2942579 ,  1.5142432 ,  1.1774076 ,  0.88153124, -1.1418657 ,
        0.9071858 , -0.37036875, -0.7320364 ,  0.13388583,  1.3081983 ,
        2.4556623 ,  1.2906868 ,  0.5216429 , -1.2663802 , -0.62655646,
       -0.3464324 ,  0.35414752, -0.19352001,  2.7272477 ,  0.7015851 ,
       -1.2175066 ,  0.35944152,  0.00731494,  0.16970608,  1.3208112 ,
       -0.24665654, -1.0809184 ,  0.3556201 , -0.34895262,  0.22785911,
        0.57528704, -0.82995737, -0.75545216,  1.4501175 ,  0.8180947 ,
        1.5672855 , -1.066282  , -1.6521634 , -0.84497553,  0.0742275 ,
        2.4019604 ,  1.9604492 ,  0.84073836, -0.7566013 , -2.4600828 ,
        0.7296744 ,  0.83801734, -1.4829856 , -0.37807947, -1.7043909 ,
        0.43703625, -0.26007292,  1.5664383 , -0.51522386,  1.6523901 ,
       -0.04317267,  0.15829101,  0.5215144 ,  0.5581539 ,  0.49906728],
      dtype=float32) to Excel
```

How can I right the whole array to a cell? How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Do you want to write all values to 1 cell or each value to separate cell?

Comment: I want to write all values to one cell so that the cell contains the whole array.

Comment: A cell can't hold an array because, in Excel, an array is spread over many cells. That's the essence of Excel. Therefore, if you wish to write the *value* of an array to a single cell you must choose a data format other than array. For example, you might convert the array to a string and, later, convert the string back to an array. The question is why you would want to do that while you can more conveniently write an array to a range and read back the range into an array without any transformation.

Comment: The exception tells you what the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

Convert `list` to `string`:

```
ws.cell(row=1, column=2, value=str(array))
```

Comment: Then, how can I later read its content as an array?

Comment: Read cell as a string and convert to array.